# Liferay 6.1. Is it possible to put cron expression for my job in portal-ext.properties?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I have a cron job

```
    <portlet>
    <portlet-name>scheduled-actions</portlet-name>
    <scheduler-entry>
        <scheduler-event-listener-class>com.example.Example</scheduler-event-listener-class>
        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <cron-trigger-value>0/15 * * * * ?</cron-trigger-value>
            </cron>
        </trigger>
    </scheduler-entry>
    <system>true</system>
</portlet>
```

Is it possible to put this cron expression (0/15 * * * * ?) in  portal-ext.properties from liferay-portlet.xml? And how to retrive it here if it is?
Thanks

Comment: I have rencently investigated a little bit because i have a similar requirement. I found that this is not possible with the standard liferay, it seems you have to create your own QuartzTask. Maybe this links can help you: [Liferay Board](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/3210146), [Dynamic Quartz Task](http://xebee.xebia.in/2012/06/15/create-update-and-delete-jobs-dynamically-in-quartz/)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add a key in portlet.properties file. We have implemented this.

portlet.properties:
trigger.key=0 0/2 * * * ?

liferay-portlet.xml:
use property-key instead of cron-trigger-value and specify "triger.key"

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing to Matthias answer. Here is what I have done to achieve it,

1. Extend your scheduler class to MVCPortlet and implement to MessageListener interface.
2. Now, override init() method by placing the following code,

   ```
   String cron = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *";// You can read it from portal-ext.properties using PropsUtil
   Trigger trigger = null;  
   try {  
   trigger = TriggerFactoryUtil.buildTrigger(TriggerType.CRON, EngageMailScheduler.class.getName(), EngageMailScheduler.class.getName(), new Date(), null, cron);  
     } catch (SchedulerException e) {  
      e.printStackTrace();  
     }  

     Message message = new Message();  
     message.put(SchedulerEngine.MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME, EngageMailScheduler.class.getName());  
     message.put(SchedulerEngine.PORTLET_ID, portlet.getPortletId());  

     try {  
   //In Liferay 6.1 use SchedulerEngineUtil, it is deprecated in Liferay 6.2
      SchedulerEngineHelperUtil.schedule(trigger, StorageType.PERSISTED, "", "liferay/scheduler_dispatch", message, 5);  
     } catch (SchedulerException e) {  
      e.printStackTrace();  
     }
   ```
3. Now, you can place your logic in the receive() method,

   ```
   public void receive(Message message) throws MessageListenerException {
        LOGGER.info("IN: Dynamic scheduler");
   }
   ```
4. Finally, give the complete path of your implemented class in liferay-portlet.xml, as below

   ```
     <portlet-class>com.test.MyScheduler</portlet-class>
   ```

Hope this helps.